# Calculate value in third column based off values in other columns but different rows

Tags: r, if-statement

Sorry if this is a trivial question or doesn't make sense, this is my first post. I'm coming from Excel where I've worked with if statements and index match functions and am trying to do something similar in R to pull data from two columns but  not necessarily the same row to get a value in a third column, my example is this

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c(1,5,4,2,3),A=c(1,0,1,1,1),B=c(0,0,1,0,0))
```

desired output:    df<-data.frame(ID=c(1,5,4,2,3),A=c(1,0,1,1,1),B=c(0,0,1,0,0),C=c(0,0,0,0,1))

What I want is to create a third column "C" that essentially follows this format:

```
Ifelse(A[ID]=1 & B[ID+1]=1 , C[ID]=1 , C[ID]=0)
```

Essentially if `A=1` in `ID` "x" and `B=1` in `ID` "x+1" then in the new column C in ID "x" =1 otherwise =0. I could order everything by ID if that makes things easier but doing it by the ID column would be ideal.

So far I've tried ifelse statements but I imagine there is probably a better way of doing this

Comment: How would your expected output look like ?

Comment: df<-data.frame(ID=c(1,5,4,2,3),A=c(1,0,1,1,1),B=c(0,0,1,0,0),C=c(0,0,0,0,1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can use `lead` to get next element after arranging the data by `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  mutate(C = as.integer(A == 1 & lead(B) == 1))

#  ID A B C
#1  1 1 0 0
#2  2 1 0 0
#3  3 1 0 1
#4  4 1 1 0
#5  5 0 0 0
```

In base R, we can do

```
df1 <- df[order(df$ID),]
df1$C <- with(df1, c(A[-nrow(df)] == 1 & tail(B, -1) == 1, 0))
```

---

Without arranging the data, we can probably do

```
transform(df, C = as.integer(A[ID] == 1 & B[match(ID + 1, ID)] == 1))
```

Comment: I think I got a variation of this to work. Out of curiosity without arranging by ID is there any other way to do this or to jump around to value more than the just the following or preceding value?

Comment: @CC90 Updated the answer to have `C` value without arranging the data by `ID`.

Comment: Your second solution in base R seems to be returning "1" in the same row as B:       ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),A=c(1,1,1,1,0),B=c(0,0,0,1,0),C=c(0,0,0,1,0))

Comment: @CC90 yes 0 should be at the end. Thank you, updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the lead function I got this to work

df <- df [order(df$ID), ]

df$C <- ifelse (df$A == 1 & lead (df$B) == 1, 1, 0)

Comment: You should accept an answer that works not add another answer the same as the other one. Check the "tick" below the above answer.